# ECONNRESET http client node.js

Tags: node.js, http

I have a node.js app, which test uptime of websites.

I'm using HTTP client library 'request' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) to scan my differents websites but from one client of mine, I frequently get error :

> ECONNRESET

All other domains (hundreds of them) are working fine. This client is using incapsula CDN.
The app is running in a docker EC2 cluster in AWS. I tried to switch today to another HTTP client library 'Axios' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) but still the same error.

Any idea on how can I get a solution ?

Comment: This sounds like a network-related issue on the app running in your EC2 docker on AWS. You would have to troubleshoot from that end, not the node side

Comment: The node app is running inside ec2 docker. The website is hosted in a different server, and cached with incapaula cdn

Comment: My mistake, you'll need to debug from the site then. It's most likely unable to cope with either the number of requests, or the load.

Comment: anything can lead to that result besides the load?

Comment: You are absolutely right, but in my experience with Node, and the `request` module, those are typically what cause it. It's really a very difficult question to answer if you don't have any logs from the server that is returning that error.

Answer (score 0):

You've to manage network error:

- devices down
- host unreachable
- service on host unreachable
- service on host restarted (TCP connexion broken)

Here is a part of a code to do this:

```js
Connexion.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(" Disconnected.  Velbus reusedSocket:",Connexion.reusedSocket, "   err.code:", err.code)
    if (Connexion.reusedSocket && err.code === 'ECONNRESET') {
        // retriableRequest();
      }
});
```

Late answer but if that could help others...